# Angular 2 Table Search Pipe Filter not working

Tags: angular, angular2-pipe

I am creating a table component in Angular 2, in which I am creating a common table search filter pipe, it is working correctly but not displaying the values in their appropriate columns.
When I start typing the search keys in the text box the filtered values are displayed correctly but not under their appropriate columns.
Sorry if this question is a duplicated one, I have spent enough time in searching the web but I was unable to get a solution for it.

Below is the code for your reference

**component.ts**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  public tableData: any = [
     {"Name":"Gaurav","Address":"Chennai","Contact":"9632587410"},
     {"Name":"Rakesh","Address":"Goa","Contact":"852397410"}
  ];
}
```

**Pipe.ts**

```js
@Pipe({
  name: 'searchPipe'
})
export class searchPipe implements PipeTransform {
   transform(value: any, args: string[]): any {
      let filter = args[0];

      if (filter && Array.isArray(value)) {
         let filterKeys = Object.keys(filter);
         return value.filter(item =>
            filterKeys.reduce((key, keyName) =>
               key && item[keyName].toUpperCase() === filter[keyName].toUpperCase(), true));
      } else {
         return value;
      }
   }
}
```

**component.html**

```html
<input type="text" #searchFilter (keyup)="0"/>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th *ngFor="let colValues of tableData | columnPipe">{{colValues}}</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let row of tableData">
    <td *ngFor="let rowValues of row | rowPipe |searchPipe:searchFilter.value">{{rowValues}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Full working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/fukkt02Pnqh32L3bRtxT?p=preview), help me in resolving the issues

Comment: you are changing the html by filtering by column, but you are not removing the undesired properties from your json object, that's why its listing in wrong order.

Comment: @Fals I can't able to get you, undesired properties in my JSON ? can you make it clear please

Comment: is there anybody could help me in this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you want it like this: https://plnkr.co/edit/olkIEiOc67Ld28NuASef?p=preview

You dont want to "hide" the whole `td`, instead you just want to "hide" the value..

```js
@Pipe({
  name: 'searchPipe'
})
export class searchPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, args: string[]): any {
    let filter = args[0];

    if (filter && Array.isArray(value)) {
      let filterKeys = Object.keys(filter);
      return value.filter(item => filterKeys.reduce((key, keyName) => key && item[keyName].toUpperCase() === filter[keyName].toUpperCase(), true));
    }
    // new case !
    else if (filter && typeof value === 'string') {
      return value.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter.toUpperCase()) >= 0 ? value : '';
    }
    else {
      return value;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<td *ngFor="let rowValues of row | rowPipe">{{ rowValues | searchPipe : searchFilter.value }}</td>
```

**UPDATE**

To show the whole row, you have to filter your `tableData`.

Change your pipe like this:

```js
@Pipe({
  name: 'searchPipe'
})
export class searchPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(values: any[], filter: string): any {
    if (!values || !values.length) return [];
    if (!filter) return values;

    filter = filter.toUpperCase();

    if (filter && Array.isArray(values)) {
      const keys = Object.keys(values[0]);
      return values.filter(v => v && keys.some(k => v[k] && v[k].toString().toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) >= 0));
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<tr *ngFor="let row of tableData | searchPipe : searchFilter.value">
  <td *ngFor="let rowValues of row | rowPipe">{{ rowValues }}</td>
</tr>
```

live demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/jXfqfCuJpKdw9HtL569T?p=preview

Comment: I have one more thing to say I need to get whole row not the single value