# Converting string value in a search pipe in angular 2

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, angular

I wrote a search pipe to search a name and returns an array contains the name. Here `searchTerm` and `key` are strings.

**My searchPipe is as follows:**

```
export class SearchPipePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(data: any[], searchTerm: string, key: string): any[] {
    searchTerm = searchTerm.toUpperCase();
    return data.filter(item => {
      return item.key.toUpperCase().indexOf(searchTerm) !== -1
    });
  }
}
```

**My html looks like**

```
<input #input placeholder="Branch Name" id="search" [(ngModel)]="search" >
<div *ngFor="let item of BranchArray | searchPipe:input.value:'Br_Name'">
  {{item.Br_Name}}
</div>
```

But I got an error as "*Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined*" because I got `item.key` as undefined in the pipe. I want to convert the key from string

**My array structure looks like**

```
BranchArray=[{"Br_Name":"Branch Name 1"},
             {"Br_Name":"Branch Name 2"},
             {"Br_Name":"Branch Name 3"},
             {"Br_Name":"Branch Name 4"},
             {"Br_Name":"Branch Name 5"},
             {"Br_Name":"Branch Name 6"},
             {"Br_Name":"Branch Name 7"},
             {"Br_Name":"Branch Name 8"}]
```

Comment: item.key will look for key in obj instead use item[key] becaue you need to look for val of key

Comment: please do refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41828440/angular-2-table-search-pipe-filter-not-working

Comment: can you please post this as an answer @vinod